# Oracle. Leave blank line on composite key level break

Tags: oracle, formatting, sqlplus

I want the output of my SQL to leave a blank line when any of three columns (a b or c below) change.

So if the table had columns a b c and d, you end up with a report like this:

```
a b c d #<- column names
------- 
1 a a a #<- V - data itself
1 a a b
        #<- level break here because 1 a b is different from 1 a a
1 a b c
```

From Googling, I have seen [BREAK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12009.htm) might solve this. 
But from what I can make out this pertains to one column.

I then thought what if I have a computed column. 
a is numeric, b & c are alphanumeric data types.. so I guess I could possibly use [CONCAT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/concat.php) plus [TO_CHAR](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php)..

I am wondering if anyone can give me some pointers?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can break on more than one column:

```
SQL> break on a skip 1 duplicates on b skip 1 duplicates on c skip 1 duplicates
SQL> select * from your_table

         A B C D
---------- - - -
         1 a a a
         1 a a b

         1 a b c




3 rows selected.
```

If you issue a plain `break` it shows what is set:

```
SQL > break
break on a skip 1 dup
          on b skip 1 dup
          on c skip 1 dup
```

Another option is to generate an extra column expression of your composite key, break on that, and set it not to display:

```
SQL> break on composite skip 1
SQ>> column composite noprint
SQL> select t.*, a||':'||b||':'||c as composite from your_table t;

         A B C D
---------- - - -
         1 a a a
         1 a a b

         1 a b c


3 rows selected.
```

which has the advantage of not showing multiple blank lines if more than one column changes at the same time.

I've separated the values with a colon; the idea of that is to use a character that doesn't appear in the values themselves, to avoid an accidental clash. If any of the columns could actually have a colon then pick something else more obscure.

Comment: In the first example you gave, is the last duplicates a mistake on your part? Have never used break before today - but at a glance that looks odd. I guess I could word it as .. does duplicates apply to column to left in sentence or right?

Comment: To the left, so `on a skip 1 duplicates` is a complete directive for column a. Without the last `dup` you'd get a null in column `c` in the second row. The `dup` means it shows the value of the break column in every row; by default it only shows the first one. I've added an alternative which might be simpler though.

Comment: right composite reads more logically to me. But with numeric column `a `you would use `to_char` right?

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a tinker around.

Comment: Sure, might be useful to format the number to a specific length; this would still work with implicit conversion of the number to a string though (as happens with `||`). Same if any of them are dates.

Comment: Ah - ok. Will be a 4 digit year - so can try  without first. Thanks

Comment: `break on composite skip 1` is giving me ORA-00900 Invalid SQL statement. Is there something I need to tweak in Oracle's settings to allow this?

Comment: `break` is a SQL\*Plus command, not an SQL statement, so that can't throw an ORA-00900. Unless you are using a different client?

Comment: Ah.. Right - did not know that - was in DBeaver. Face palms!

Comment: Think it's going to be easier to export to Excel and do it from that...

Comment: This is something the presentation should be doing. I guess it's possible to make a query do that, or appear to do that, but it would be a nasty hack.